# Linear Algebra - Linear Inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My professor wrote this on my homework.

> Either my uncle is an art critic or muffins are unhealthy.
>
> If aliens write poetry, then muffins are unhealthy and my uncle is an art critic
>
> But it is assuredly not true both that muffins are unhealthy and
>   aliens do not write poetry
>
> ---
>
> Hence, muffins are unhealthy and my uncle is an art critic

Valid or invalid? Why?

p.s. this is word for word.

This is what I have

> $P \lor Q$
>
> $R \Rightarrow (P \lor Q)$
>
> $\neg(Q \land R)$
>
> ---
>
> $Q \land P$
>
> Valid

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to the body?

Answer (score 0):

From statement 1 we see that it is not possible that your uncle is an art critic AND muffins are unhealthy. Since both is not possible, that means that aliens do not write poetry, from second statement. In statement 3, there is once again an OR statement. We know that aliens do not write poetry and therefore muffins cannot be unhealthy. Is your uncle then really an art critic? Go back to the first statement.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the delayed response. So from you logic, statement one would make the second part of statement two impossible, therefore **Aliens do not write poetry**. From this we get, **muffins are healthy**. Going back to statement one we get, **My uncle is an art critic**. This would make the statement invalid. I get that, but I am not sure I understand why the first statement makes it impossible for both to be true. It is an or, so that means at least one has to be true. Is it because the "either" is there? -Thanks

Comment: Either...or... means that not both can be true. I edited my answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

Your symbolization is not correct. Using:

$P$: My uncle is an art critic

$Q$: Muffins are unhealthy

$R$: Aliens write poetry

The argument is:

$P \lor Q$

$R \rightarrow (Q \land P)$

$\neg (Q \land \neg R)$

$\therefore Q \land P$

This is easily seen to be invalid by setting $P$ to true, and $Q$ and $R$ to false.

Comment: Hi, I realized I messed up statement two after I posted, but I did not realize I messed up three as well. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, I created a truth table for your scenario, [truth table here](https://i.imgur.com/rgKJ1Hp.png). This is going to sound stupid, so I apologize in advance. Why did you pick  to set P=True, Q=False, and R=False? With these values, the conclusion is false in the truth table. Were you just picking three random values where the three statements are true, and the conclusion is false? If so, than that is the only possible combination or scenario that would prove this statement in valid. -Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jwags I purposely searched for a counterexample, making the premises true and the conclusion false. So here is how I came to the values: I try to make the conclusion false, so I cannot have both $P$ and $Q$ true. bUt that means that the consequent of premise 2 is false, and for that premise to still be true, you need to set $R$ to false. But if $R$ is false, then $\neg R$ is true, so for the third premise to be true, and thus for $Q \land \neg R$ to be false, you need to set $Q$ to false.  But by premise 1, one of $P$ and $Q$ is true, so $P$ has to be true. And there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

If aliens do not write poetry, then muffins are not unhealthy (by statement 3) and so your uncle is an art critic (by statement 1).  However, there is no contradiction in this.  Rather, we have found a situation where all three statements are true, but the conclusion is false.  Statement 1 is true because your uncle is an art critic.  Statement 2 is true because aliens do not write poetry.  Statement 3 is true because muffins are not unhealthy.  The conclusion is false because muffins are not unhealthy.